# Add value from @string to my array.xml

Tags: android, arrays

I have my array.xml to fill preferences value.

```
<string-array name="language">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>German</item> 
    <item>Russian</item>
    <item>Italian</item>
</string-array>
```

To translate the items I put them in various string.xml file, how can I add the values from  @string/english, @string/german etc.?

Comment: What is wrong with <item>@string/english</item> and then <string name="english">English</string> in strings.xml ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
res/values/array.xml
res/values-fr/array.xml
res/values-ja/array.xml
```

And so on...

If your issue is that you want to substitute the `<item>` value dynamically, you might have to do this in code. Check out this post: [dynamic parameters in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397613/android-parameters-in-strings-xml-possible)

Comment: ops... it was simple... I didn't think to duplicate array.xml :( thanks

Answer (score 10):

do this...

```
<string name="jan">January</string>
<string name="fev">February</string>
<string name="mar">March</string>

<string-array name="year">
    <item name="jan">@string/jan</item>
    <item name="fev">@string/fev</item>
    <item name="mar">@string/mar</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just create string arrays in `string.xml` and other `string.xml(ru)` etc.

See below code snippet :-

string.xml

```
<!-- Language array -->
<string-array name="languages">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Russian</item>
</string-array>
```

string.xml(ru)

```
<!-- Language array -->
<string-array name="languages">
    <item>английский</item>
    <item>русский</item>
</string-array>
```