# How to translate items in a String Array?

Tags: android, arrays, xml, translation

I have some string arrays and lot of string items in them which I am unable to translate using the Translation Editor.

```
<string-array name="miocene_infos_list">
    <item>The Miocene era was mostly characterized by arrival of a bizarre array of mammalian megafauna. Astrapotherium was a
        hooved ungulate that looked like a cross between an elephant, a tapir and a rhinoceros. It was a distance relative
        of horse. It had short, prehensile trunk and powerful tusks. It\'s hind limbs were significantly weaker than the fore limbs.
        The nostrils of Astrapotherium were also set unusually high which shows that this prehistoric herbivore may have adapted
        partly amphibious lifestyle, like a modern hippopotamus. The Greek meaning for Astrapotherium was \' Lighting Beast \' which
        is inappropriate for such an animal that might have been a slow plant eater.</item>

    <item>Barbourofelis was the only member of its Sabre Tooth Cats breed to colonize late Miocene North America. This megafauna
        mammal possessed some of the largest canines of any saber toothed cat. This cat was heavily muscled and was big as the modern
        Lion. These cats might have walked in a Bear like fashion.</item>

    <item>The largest prehistoric dog that ever lived, Epicyon was a true \'Canid\' and belonged to the same speiceis as wolves,
        hyenas and modern dogs. Some of the largest species of Epicyon weighed more than a full grown human. I had unusually powerful
        jaws and teeth. Due to this reason, it\'s head looked more like that of a big cat than that of a dog or wolf. It may have
        hunted alone or in packs and also might have fed on dead carcasses. All of the species of Epicyon were discovered in
        western North America</item>

    <item>Brygmophyseter was an opportunistic predator, chomping down on penguins, sharks, seals and even other prehistoric whales.
        was pretty large in size. Brygmophyseter would also have lived in social groups called pods, and probably hunted in packs,
        like modern Orcas. Brygmophyseter was likely among the apex predators of its time. It teeth were 14 cm long. It may have
        also possessed Sonar capabilities to detect underwater preys. Its large head might have been used to ram opponents during
        fights.</item>

    <item>
        Megalodon was the largest prehistoric shark and also the largest marine predator in the history of planet. It outweighs ancient reptiles like
        Liopleurodon and Kronosaurus. It may have looked like an over sized Great White Shark. It fed on dolphins, squids, fish, and even giant turtles.
        Megalodon may even have attacked the giant whale Leviathan. Megalodon\'s biting power was very large and delivered 1.8 tons of force. This amount of
        force is enough to cursh the skull of a prehistoric whale as easy as a a grape. The teeth of this prehistoric shark were over half a foot long,
        serrated, and heart-shaped. No wonder why it is named Big Tooth. However there is no evidence on how this enormous creature was vanished off from
        the face of Earth. What a wonder it is.
    </item>
</string-array>
```

These items does not appear in the Translations Editor window. So how can I translate them? Is there any other way?

Comment: You provide different resource files in the different `values` folders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create diffrent folder structure in res 
like 
values
valuse-fr
values-sv 
create values folder as above for the laguage you want to support.
put strings.xml in each folder with values in that particular laguage.

Now whenever you are using them in xml access them as @string/string_name.
While accessing them from java use context.getString(R.string.string_name).

Will work . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

```
res/values/array.xml
res/values-fr/array.xml
res/values-ja/array.xml
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293044/add-value-from-string-to-my-array-xml?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: This answer means that the array will have the same name in any of the translated versions of your strings.xml file. For example, in strings.xml in the default directory: <string-array name="tts_languages">
        <item>english</item>
        <item>french</item>...</string-array>

Comment: This answer means that the array will have the same name in any of the translated versions of your strings.xml file. For example, in strings.xml in the default directory: <string-array name="tts_languages">
        <item>english</item>
        <item>french</item>...</string-array>. Now in the file: es/strings.xml located in the directory for translations into e.g. Spanish: <string-array name="tts_languages">
        <item>inglés</item>
        <item>francés</item>...</string-array>

Comment: If you have not created the Spanish directory yet which contains the strings.xml with the spanish version of your Strings, it can be created automatically when you translate a String term e.g: <string name="name">"NAME: "</string> by using the menu for translations. To keep consistency within an array and its translated versions, copy them all to a spreadsheet program, e.g. Excel, with each array occupying a column, and where every line will match the correct translated version. When you modify or add or delete a line, the changes will affect all the arrays in the right position. Cheers.