# How to pass Data to the getText?

Tags: android

I have the following String ressource:

```
<string name="foo">This is a {0} test. Hello {1}</string>
```

Now I want to pass the values `1` and `foo` when calling:

```
getResources().getText(R.string.foo)
```

how to make this? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getResources().getString(R.string.foo, 1, "foo");` but string should be using [string format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) ... so your string in string should looks like:

```
<string name="foo">This is a %d test. Hello %s</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure if Java has something like this inbuilt. I did once write a method that would do the exact thing you're looking for, however:

```
public static String format(String str, Object... objects)
{
    String tag = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        tag = "\\{" + i + "\\}";
        str = str.replaceFirst(tag, objects[i].toString());
    }

    return str;
}
```

And this would format the string, to replace the '{i}' with the objects passed; just like in C#.

example:

```
format(getResources().getString(R.string.foo), "cool", "world!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way :
     `string name="foo">This is a %d test. Hello %s string>` 

with

    `getString(R.string.foo, 1, "foo");`

Source : [Are parameters in strings.xml possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397613/parameters-in-strings-xml-possible)

You can find more information on formatting and formats here : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simplest way to do what you're wanting is to save the line of code you have to a variable then use the Java String replace() function.

```
String fooText = getResources().getText(R.string.foo);
fooText = fooText.replace("{0}", myZeroVar);
fooText = fooText.replace("{1}", myOneVar);
```