# Android Studio Strings

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Quick question:

I know a small amount of Java, and I'm working on my first very basic Android application.

I just want it to say "Your device is: Build.MODEL" but I can't figure out how to get that string to display in the XML TextView.

Comment: `"Your device is:" + Build.MODEL;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Studio to generate a "blank activity", you will find it has a single String "Hello World" in it. Take it from there - and get back to SOF with further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see this question: [Are parameters in strings.xml possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397613/are-parameters-in-strings-xml-possible)

Try to using String paremeters on XML to do that

Answer (score 0):

in Java

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewByid(R.id.myTextViewName);
myText.setText("your device is:".concat(Build.MODEL));
```

(in your xml the TextView must be named myTextViewName

That's all