# Translate String AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, internationalization, translate

I want to translate this code:

```
List.add("  Temperature: " + matrix[1][2] + " ºC");
```

I want to translate the word "Temperature:" but I don`t know how to put it on Strings.xml

EDIT: I want to know how to add Temperature on Strings.xml and then make a translation

Comment: Translate? What does it mean? you don't know how to add Temperature on Strings.xml?

Comment: I want to know how to add Temperature on Strings.xml and then make a translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it on `Strings.xml` you have to add this :

```
<string name="Temperature">Temperature: </string>
```

Then if you want to use it from `Strings.xml` you do this as follows :

```
List.add(getString(R.string.Temperature) + matrice[1][2] + " ºC");
```

To translate it you'll have to create different values directories for the language with [the suffix of the language code](https://github.com/championswimmer/android-locales).

[See the documents](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

### EDIT(parameters String)

Adding the parameters as [@trooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975741/trooper) said, would be like this :

Your `Strings.xml` should be

```
<string name="Temperature">Temperature: %1$s ºC</string>
```

Then in your java code you have to use this :

```
List.add(String.format(getString(R.string.Temperature), matrice[1][2]));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I did it but it works without the ""                                            List.add(getString(R.string.Temperature) + matrice[1][2] + " ºC");

Comment: Woops, my bad misstyped :P, glad to hear that... mark this answer as a correct if it helped to you :D

Comment: @Manumarigle also consider parameterizing your string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397613/are-parameters-in-strings-xml-possible