# Parameter in strings.xml does't work

Tags: android, xml, string, parameters

I don't understand this anymore.
I try to write a TextView

```
android:text="@string/dbVer"
```

define in strings.xml

```
<string name="dbVer">db %1$s</string>
```

and in Activity

```
int dbTag = Integer.parseInt(yearDay.format(new Date(new File(databasePath + "/ean_database.db").lastModified())));
String dbVer = String.format(getString(R.string.dbVer), dbTag );
```

The TextView is still showing: db %1$s

The nearest answer I found: [Are parameters in strings.xml possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397613/are-parameters-in-strings-xml-possible) is similar but in fact something is wrong for me.

Comment: After the code you posted in your Activity, do you call `setText()` on the TextView?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the result "db %1$s" because you are creating a string and assigning that as its value in the strings.xml file between these ><. What are you trying to have it show instead?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> android:text="@string/dbVer"
> ```

This refers to your format string and displays the raw format string you're seeing.

> ```
> int dbTag = Integer.parseInt(yearDay.format(new Date(new File(databasePath + "/ean_database.db").lastModified())));
> String dbVer = String.format(getString(R.string.dbVer), dbTag );
> ```

This creates a new string `dbVer` using the format string from resources.

What is missing is that you need to set this new string as your `TextView`'s text:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id); // assuming an activity
tv.setText(dbVer);
```