# Is it possible to pass transparency in colors.xml file using parameters?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have these variables in `colors.xml`

```
<color name="white1">#FFFFFF</color> <!-- 100% of transparency -->
<color name="white2">#BFFFFFFF</color> <!-- 75% of transparency -->
<color name="white3">#80FFFFFF</color> <!-- 50% of transparency -->
<color name="white4">#40FFFFFF</color> <!-- 25% of transparency -->
<color name="white5">#00FFFFFF</color> <!-- 0% of transparency -->
```

Is there any way to pass transparency via parameters such as `strings.xml` in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397613/are-parameters-in-strings-xml-possible) or another way instead of make many variables

Comment: as far as i know no you can't. you can set a color programtically and you can also set alpha to view dynamically

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm using this view `com.google.android.material.slider.Slider` and this view has many attributes relating colors and if I set `android:alpha="0.25"` this will apply to the whole view. I wish my English is clear to understand.

Comment: you need to have those colors in colors.xml

Comment: I thought there is a better way of that, By the way thank you.